# inline editing in angularjs save item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to avoid any directive as I want to learn more, but I can't get it working **on the save part**.

partially working code here : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3789/

is it good to avoid using `$index`? because I use a lots of `this`

```
$scope.saveEditedTask = function(i){
    this.editable = false;  
}
```

Comment: Please upgrade angular version and confirm the issue. And please also add all the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @lib3d click on the code link above, everything is there.

Comment: Yes I know, it's for your question to survice jsfiddle drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change text field to
`<input ng-show="editable" type="text" ng-model="task.name"/>`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pnj5X9aSxzVWj5DjRbGA?p=preview)

You were not using the angular directive ng-model which bi-directionally binds the field to object.

Comment: great answer, how dumb am I never thought of that! Erm, how to make it focus once the edit link is clicked? so far I seeing by using directive to make the field focus, that's way too much of code.